# How to format number in D3.js /C3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, c3.js

My Application supports several number formats listed below and would like to show the numbers c3 charts in that format.

```
NUMBER_FORMAT1="#,###.##" ( decimal separator . and thousand separator , )
NUMBER_FORMAT2="#.###,##" ( decimal separator , and thousand separator . )
NUMBER_FORMAT3="# ###,##" ( decimal separator , and thousand separator space )
NUMBER_FORMAT4="# ###.##" ( decimal separator . and thousand separator space )
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use d3's format functions (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting) for this

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 20050, 100],
        ]
    },
    tooltip: {
        format: {
            value: function(value) {
                return d3.format(",.2f")(value)
            }
        }
    }
});
```

gives the tooltips in the first of your formats. You can use this anywhere C3 accepts a format specifier.

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6j2hys0s/

---

However for the rest of your formats, you'd have to use a regex to swap out the , and the . with the characters you want.

```
// #.###,##
return d3.format(",.2f")(value).replace('.', ' ').replace(/,/g, '.').replace(' ', ',')

// # ###,##
return d3.format(",.2f")(value).replace(/,/g, ' ').replace(/\./, ',');

// # ###.##
return d3.format(",.2f")(value).replace(/,/g, ' ');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set your own format function

```
axis : {
    x : {
        type : 'linear',
        tick: {
            format: function (x) { return x + ' km'; }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the concept of locale supported in  d3

1. Create 4 locale as per the number formats
2. specify number style

Sample code

```
// #,###.##
 var D3_LOCALE_NUMBER_FORMAT1 = d3.locale({
    "decimal": ".",
    "thousands": ",",
    "grouping": [3],
    "currency": ["USD", ""],
    "dateTime": "%a %b %e %X %Y",
    "date": "%d-%m-%Y",
    "time": "%H:%M:%S",
    "periods": ["AM", "PM"],
    "days": ["Zondag", "Maandag", "Dinsdag", "Woensdag", "Donderdag", "Vrijdag", "Zaterdag"],
    "shortDays": ["Zo", "Ma", "Di", "Wo", "Do", "Vr", "Za"],
    "months": ["Januari", "Februari", "Maart", "April", "Mei", "Juni", "Juli", "Augustus", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"],
    "shortMonths": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mei", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec"]
});

// #.###,##
var D3_LOCALE_NUMBER_FORMAT2 = d3.locale({
    "decimal": ",",
    "thousands": ".",
    "grouping": [3],
    "currency": ["USD", ""],
    "dateTime": "%a %b %e %X %Y",
    "date": "%d-%m-%Y",
    "time": "%H:%M:%S",
    "periods": ["AM", "PM"],
    "days": ["Zondag", "Maandag", "Dinsdag", "Woensdag", "Donderdag", "Vrijdag", "Zaterdag"],
    "shortDays": ["Zo", "Ma", "Di", "Wo", "Do", "Vr", "Za"],
    "months": ["Januari", "Februari", "Maart", "April", "Mei", "Juni", "Juli", "Augustus", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"],
    "shortMonths": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mei", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec"]
});

// # ###,##
var D3_LOCALE_NUMBER_FORMAT3 = d3.locale({
    "decimal": ",",
    "thousands": " ",
    "grouping": [3],
    "currency": ["USD", ""],
    "dateTime": "%a %b %e %X %Y",
    "date": "%d-%m-%Y",
    "time": "%H:%M:%S",
    "periods": ["AM", "PM"],
    "days": ["Zondag", "Maandag", "Dinsdag", "Woensdag", "Donderdag", "Vrijdag", "Zaterdag"],
    "shortDays": ["Zo", "Ma", "Di", "Wo", "Do", "Vr", "Za"],
    "months": ["Januari", "Februari", "Maart", "April", "Mei", "Juni", "Juli", "Augustus", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"],
    "shortMonths": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mei", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec"]
});

// # ###.##
var D3_LOCALE_NUMBER_FORMAT4 = d3.locale({
    "decimal": ".",
    "thousands": " ",
    "grouping": [3],
    "currency": ["USD", ""],
    "dateTime": "%a %b %e %X %Y",
    "date": "%d-%m-%Y",
    "time": "%H:%M:%S",
    "periods": ["AM", "PM"],
    "days": ["Zondag", "Maandag", "Dinsdag", "Woensdag", "Donderdag", "Vrijdag", "Zaterdag"],
    "shortDays": ["Zo", "Ma", "Di", "Wo", "Do", "Vr", "Za"],
    "months": ["Januari", "Februari", "Maart", "April", "Mei", "Juni", "Juli", "Augustus", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"],
    "shortMonths": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mei", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec"]
});

 var yAxisNumberFormat=NUMBER_FORMAT1; 
 var defaultNumberFormat=NUMBER_FORMAT1;

 //Scientific Prefix "s" because on Y axis we show 1000 as 1k, 1000000 as 1M 
 var numberStyle_Scientific="s";
 // Fixed number format "f" because we dont want to show any precision(decimal) numbers
 // the , (comma) indicates SHOW thousands separator.
 //( NOTE:This doesn't mean that comma(,) is the thousand separartor.)
 var numberStyle_Fixed=",f";

 if(USER_NUMBER_FORMAT==NUMBER_FORMAT1){
    yAxisNumberFormat=D3_LOCALE_NUMBER_FORMAT1.numberFormat(numberStyle_Scientific); 
    defaultNumberFormat=D3_LOCALE_NUMBER_FORMAT1.numberFormat(numberStyle_Fixed); 
 } else if(USER_NUMBER_FORMAT==NUMBER_FORMAT2){ 
    yAxisNumberFormat=D3_LOCALE_NUMBER_FORMAT2.numberFormat(numberStyle_Scientific); 
    defaultNumberFormat=D3_LOCALE_NUMBER_FORMAT2.numberFormat(numberStyle_Fixed); 
 } else if(USER_NUMBER_FORMAT==NUMBER_FORMAT3){ 
    yAxisNumberFormat=D3_LOCALE_NUMBER_FORMAT3.numberFormat(numberStyle_Scientific);
    defaultNumberFormat=D3_LOCALE_NUMBER_FORMAT3.numberFormat(numberStyle_Fixed);   
 } else if(USER_NUMBER_FORMAT==NUMBER_FORMAT4){ 
    yAxisNumberFormat=D3_LOCALE_NUMBER_FORMAT4.numberFormat(numberStyle_Scientific); 
    defaultNumberFormat=D3_LOCALE_NUMBER_FORMAT4.numberFormat(numberStyle_Fixed); 
 }
```

with this in place you just need to use defaultNumberFormat(yourNumber);
yAxisNumberFormat(yourNumber);

Answer (score 1):

I want to add this link to an awesome [demo page](http://bl.ocks.org/zanarmstrong/raw/05c1e95bf7aa16c4768e/). It is a playground when you can choose what a format specifier you need for your case. It is very useful when you do not remember/know what a format specifier you should pass to your `d3.format` function.